# Obtaining the datalists row details

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have the following itemTemplate in my datalist

```
          <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Select" autopostback="True" runat="server">'<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>'</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
```

This is my dataList mark up:

```
   <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AllQuestionAskedDataSource"
            GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyField="ThreadsID" >
```

This is the sqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllQuestionAskedDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ThreadTitle, ThreadsID
    FROM Threads
WHERE UsersID=@UserID" onselecting="AllQuestionAskedDataSource_Selecting">
```

I am trying to use one of the following events handlers:

```
protected void DataList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

What I want to obtain in one of those event handlers the ThreadID associated with the row selected (by clicking on the row in the datalist) and get the ThreadTitle parameter from the specific row selected..

How can I achieve that task?

I basically want to retrieve the sql parameters that i feed into the sqldatasource, relating to the specific row clicked!!

Solved it myself:

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
    string threadTitle = link.Text;

    string recordID = (DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]).ToString();
    string special = "";
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like..

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Will give you current data key value
    Int32 threadID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
    // if you want value of your control
    (ControlTypd)e.Item.FindControl("ControldId")
}
```

Comment: the e.CommandArgument throws a Format Exception . I set this as my dataKeyField...ThreadsID. I want it to be my primary key for each row that i use ...

Comment: Muhammad, I solved it..here is the solution above..updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think, that the following code will work:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e) {
    DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
    int threadID = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["ThreadsID"]);
}
```

OR

```
protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataRowView rowView = DataList1.SelectedItem.DataItem as DataRowView;
        int threadID = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["ThreadsID"]);
    }
```

Comment: The row is null everytime i click on the item (linkbutton)..Nullerexception is thrown.Also how do I retrieve the DatakeyName = "ThreadID" that is associated with the row?

Comment: please set the breakpoint at the _int threadID_ line and check the type of the e.Item.DataItem property in the QuickWatch window.  what is it?

Comment: Selected inex changed.. hmmm.. i will try , one moment

Comment: no..row view is null.. I dont think it is the way to do it.. i retrieved ThreadTitle like this:LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton2");

Comment: please check the type of the DataList1.SelectedItem.DataItem property.  What is it?